# How to get selected items from QComboBox to be displayed in QTableWidget in PyQt5? (QComboBox has checkbox to pick items)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I have QTableWidget in which I have QComboBox in each row for particular column. My each QCombobox has multiple values with checkboxes. I want to display selected item/s from each combobox in the next respective column 'SelectedMonths' in the same row and remove them when unchecked (Vice-versa).

Until now I have Script ready which gives me what all items have been checked/unchecked but I dont know how to get the index of the row for which combobox is activated.

Snippet to get the workflow

[image]

**Sample Code:**

**Code Generated by QtDesigner: Demo.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(464, 291)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 30, 411, 221))
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(1)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setItem(0, 1, item)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.tableWidget.isSortingEnabled()
        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
        item = self.tableWidget.item(0, 0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Select Months"))
        item = self.tableWidget.item(0, 1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Selected Months"))
        self.tableWidget.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Code which I have written: DemoCode.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QTableWidgetItem
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItem, QStandardItemModel
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

from Demo import Ui_MainWindow

def CheckableCombobox(combo, options):
    model = QStandardItemModel(len(options), 1)
    firstItem = QtGui.QStandardItem("SelectMonths")
    firstItem.setBackground(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(200, 200, 200)))
    firstItem.setSelectable(False)
    model.setItem(0, 0, firstItem)
    for i, area in enumerate(options):
        item = QStandardItem(area)
        item.setFlags(Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
        item.setData(Qt.Unchecked, Qt.CheckStateRole)
        model.setItem(i+1, 0, item)
    combo.setModel(model)

class DemoCode(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):                    
    def __init__(self):
        super(DemoCode, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)  

        self.rowPosition = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
        for row in range(0,3):
            self.tableWidget.insertRow(self.rowPosition)
            for column in range(0,2):
                if column == 0:
                    self.ComboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
                    dtStart = date.today()
                    self.Monthlist = []
                    for n in range(1, 5):
                        self.Monthlist.append((dtStart + relativedelta(months=-n)).strftime('1-%b-%Y'))
                    CheckableCombobox(self.ComboBox, self.Monthlist)
                    self.ComboBox.model().itemChanged.connect(self.on_itemChanged)
                    self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(self.rowPosition, column, self.ComboBox)
                elif column == 1:
                    item = QTableWidgetItem('')
                    self.tableWidget.setItem(self.rowPosition, column, item)

            self.rowPosition += 1

        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(1,150)

    def on_itemChanged(self, item):
        current_state = item.data(Qt.CheckStateRole)
        print(current_state, item.text())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = DemoCode()    
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should find a way to keep track of the row for each combo model, so that you can set the item text accordingly.

Note that I changed your code logic a bit, as there were some conceptual mistakes:

- don't set instance attributes if they are not required: all those `self.rowPosition`, `self.monthList`, etc, change everytime the for loop cycles, and you don't need them after that;
- avoid using uppercase names for variables and functions
- the month list is always the same, build it before the for cycle instead of computing it each time
- instead of setting the model to the combo in the function, make it return the model

**Edit**: added copy function after comment request

```
def createModel(options):
    model = QStandardItemModel(len(options), 1)
    firstItem = QtGui.QStandardItem("SelectMonths")
    firstItem.setBackground(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(200, 200, 200)))
    firstItem.setSelectable(False)
    model.setItem(0, 0, firstItem)
    for i, area in enumerate(options):
        item = QStandardItem(area)
        item.setFlags(Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
        item.setData(Qt.Unchecked, Qt.CheckStateRole)
        model.setItem(i+1, 0, item)
    return model

class DemoCode(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):                    
    def __init__(self):
        super(DemoCode, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)  

        monthList = [(date.today() + relativedelta(months=-n)).strftime('1-%b-%Y') for n in range(1, 5)]
        self.models = {}

        rows = self.tableWidget.rowCount()
        for row in range(rows, rows + 3):
            self.tableWidget.insertRow(row)
            comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
            model = createModel(monthList)
            comboBox.setModel(model)
            model.itemChanged.connect(lambda _, row=row: self.on_itemChanged(row))
            self.models[row] = model
            self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(row, 0, comboBox)
            item = QTableWidgetItem()
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row, 1, item)

        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(1,150)

    def on_itemChanged(self, tableRow):
        model = self.models[tableRow]
        items = []
        for row in range(model.rowCount()):
            comboItem = model.index(row, 0)
            if comboItem.data(Qt.CheckStateRole):
                items.append(comboItem.data())
        self.tableWidget.item(tableRow, 1).setText(', '.join(items))

    def copyFromRow(self, tableRow):
        sourceModel = self.models[tableRow]
        checkedRows = []
        for row in range(sourceModel.rowCount()):
            if sourceModel.index(row, 0).data(Qt.CheckStateRole):
                checkedRows.append(row)
        for model in self.models.values():
            if model == sourceModel:
                continue
            for row in range(model.rowCount()):
                model.setData(
                    model.index(row, 0), 
                    Qt.Checked if row in checkedRows else Qt.Unchecked, 
                    Qt.CheckStateRole)
```

I'd also suggest to remove the "Select Months" and "Selected Months" items, and use them as table headers.

Comment: Thanks @musicamante It worked!! it would be great if you could also tell me i f want to copy selected items from first row to all rows by pressing a button, how can i do it? what i mean is if i pick two items from first row, it will keep both items checked in other comboboxes as well as in the column beside combobox.

Comment: @VirenKheni I'm not sure I've understood. Let's see: if I press a button, it will set the checked state of the first row's combobox to all the other comboboxes? What about the items in other comboboxes that are already checked, should they be unchecked?

Comment: yes it should overwrite with first row's selection. after this if i select/remove new items in second or third row, selection changes accordingly.

Comment: @VirenKheni I've updated the answer, the function uses `tableRow` to access the correct model, remember that if you are still using the first row for the "headers" (but, again, you shouldn't), you have to take that into account; so, in your case, you should call `copyFromRow(1)` to copy from the first combo, while normally rows should start from 0.

Comment: Thanks! It's Flawless! :)